# How to set Weight to make bottom view occupy remaining space Android

Tags: android, android-layout, expandable, android-layout-weight

I want to model my layout screen in the following 2 parts.

1. Basic Information related Linear layout with expandable view initially 20 % of screen height.
2. Bottom List view occupy Remaining Space.

But When the top view is expanded then i want to make it height upto 50 % and the bottom listview should start then after.

I have attached image for reference.

I have tried setting the layout_weight of top and bottom layout. But not able to find out exact solution. May be i am missing some points.

Let me know if you need more information from my end.

Thanks in Advance.

regards,
Rakesh

[image: Layout requirement]

Comment: You whaterver height for your upper view , in your lower view set like this <ListView android:height="0dp" anbdroid:layout_weight="1" /> and don'st set layout weight to upper view

Comment: Done. Also set the maximum height of scrollview by writing custom scrollview . So no need to set weight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the current weight from the top view and in the listview set `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_height="0dp"`. This makes the ListView to take whatever height left in the screen.

Comment: thanks for your reply, But i wanted to make sure that top scoll view maximum height should not go beyond half the height of view. I did it by custom Scrollview. But your answer is correct. Thanks.